# Pandas dataframe displaying rows twice in Windows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

***Stoppress; I did some more testing and it seems that the code works fine, until Pandas Datareader in installed, and then all of the dataframes print double data. So there may be a bug in Pandas Datareader that is causing this.****

I am using **Python 3.7** on Windows 10, and have just installed pandas and other key components. When I create a pandas dataframe, it seems to work correctly with processing the dataframe but it displays the rows twice. It shows the same index numbers and data twice.

I have been banging my head against a brick wall trying to troubleshoot this, and there doesn't seem to be anything about this online. I have tried this on a second computer and get the same reult. I have also tried it in Python shell, windows command prompt with python, and Spyder. The biggest mystery to me is how no one else has experienced this same problem.

I have tried using the various functions to delete duplicates and group by functions but the problem must be a display problem because the number of rows stated in Spyder, and from the query row count its clear that this does not equal the number of rows displayed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3,4,5], 'b': [6, 7, 8,9,10], 'c': [11, 12, 13,14,15], \
                  'd': [16, 17, 18,19,20], 'e': [21, 22, 23,24,25], 'f': [26, 27, 28,29,30]})

print(df)
```

Output:

.. ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..

> a   b   c   d   e   f 
> 0   1  6   11  16  21  26 
> 1   2 
>   7   12  17  22  27 
> 2   3  8   13  18  23  28 
> 3   4  9   14  19
>   24  29 
> 1   2  7   12  17  22  27 
> 2   3  8   13  18  23  28
>   
> 3   4  9   14  19  24  29 
> 4   5  10  15  20  25  30

The expected result is to show the dataset once, but it is showing it twice.

Comment: Could I just clarify. The code you see above were run as just those two lines with no other code and that is the result it produced.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this now: Having removed Pandas Datareader and the following line, it now works:

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', -1)

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work fine for me. Try running it in a different environment, if it still contains this same problem, it could be an issue with some of the dependencies during the installation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3,4,5], 'b': [6, 7, 8,9,10], 'c': [11, 12, 13,14,15], \
              'd': [16, 17, 18,19,20], 'e': [21, 22, 23,24,25], 'f': [26, 27, 28,29,30]})

print(df)
```

I get:

```
      a   b   c   d   e   f
   0  1   6  11  16  21  26
   1  2   7  12  17  22  27
   2  3   8  13  18  23  28
   3  4   9  14  19  24  29
   4  5  10  15  20  25  30
```

If you run it somewhere else and you still have the same problem, you might want to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Hi there- thanks for your comment. I have now tested this on 2 Windows 10 macines and an Ubuntu machine.  I just found out something else which I have appended to the OP which is:

***Stoppress: I did some more testing and it seems that the code works fine, until Pandas Datareader in installed, and then all of the dataframes print double data. So there may be a bug in Pandas Datareader that is causing this.****